# How to force file download in Moodle "manually"?

Tags: php, download, moodle

I am trying to show a download popup when clicking a link. I retrieve correctly the file using the **file storage**. I've tried with as per [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer)
```

But doesn't work. I've also tried with `$PAGE` variable also, just in case, but neither.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the most important header to provide when trying to setup file serving is `Content-Type`. Since you always want a download prompt, you don't even have to check the proper mimetype, you can always use:

```
application/octet-stream
```

Although it would be wise to also use:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=""
```

Or your browser might say something such as:

> You have chosen to open: download.php, which is: php file, from http://example.com

Therefore we end up with this:

```
$file = 'path/to/monkey.gif';

header('Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
readfile($file);
exit();
```

You can easily replace `readfile` with whatever `moodle` uses.